# Set a function to be one of pool of possible functions

Tags: python, decorator

### The Problem:

In my code I want to use a function `f`. What `f` does depends on some external setting, call it `active_fun`. If it is set to `"f1"`, then `f` should do something (namely what `f1` does), if it is set to `"f2"`, then `f` should do what `f2` does. The function don't differ on their input arguments. An easy example can look like this:

```
def f1(x):
    return x + 2

def f2(x):
    return x + 20

# somehow specify the "active" function
active_fun = "f1"

# do something to make sure, f is set to the "active" function 
for current_fun, fun in zip(["f1", "f2"], [f1, f2]):
    if current_fun == active_fun:
        f = fun
        break

# From here, only refer to f(), as it is the correct "active" fun
print f(2)
```

I feel that this can be done with a decorator, but i just don't know how. Any advice on this would be quite helpful.

### My alternative approaches:

I came up with some alternatives.
1) Always update the definition of `f`, when the value of `active_fun` changes.

```
# alternative solution (1):
def f(x):
    for current_fun, fun in zip(["f1", "f2"], [f1, f2]):
        if current_fun == active_fun:
            return fun(x)
```

2) Whenever the value of `active_fun` changes, i run a function, which returns `f` with the correct definition:

```
# alternative solution (2):
def on_active_fun_change(active_fun):
     for current_fun, fun in zip(["f1", "f2"], [f1, f2]):
        if current_fun == active_fun:
            return fun

f = on_active_fun_change(active_fun)
```

I am not totally happy with any of them, cause I think the pythonic way would be doing this with a decorator.

### Additional (not neccessary) info about the usecase:

I am writing a GUI, this GUI shows some plots. Suppose it can either do a scatter-plot or a line-plot of two timeseries. Each time something changes, the plot will be redrawn because the function `on_change` will be called. Now `on_change` should know if it is plotting a scatter-plot or a line-plot.

Comment: You can assign functions like any other objects; so perhaps a GUI radiobutton sets `plotting_fn = scatter_plot` or `plotting_fn = line_plot`, and then the GUI reacts to new data by calling `plotting_fn()`.

Comment: @cphlewis That sounds nice, too!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

```
func_map = {'f1': f1, 'f2': f2}
active_fun = 'f1'
```

**Option 1:**

```
func_map[active_fun](3)
Out[86]: 5
```

**Option 2:**

```
def map_func(x, active_func='f1'):
    return func_map[active_func](x)

map_func(3, 'f1')
Out[98]: 5

map_func(3, 'f2')
Out[99]: 23
```

Comment: I like the idea of a dict instead of two lists combined with zip.

Answer (score 1):

import random

def f1(x):
    return x + 2

def f2(x):
    return x + 20

funcs = [f1, f2]
randFunc = random.choice(funcs)  # pick a random function from the list
randFunc.**name**

Output:

```
In [8]: %paste
def f1(x):
    return x + 2

def f2(x):
    return x + 20


funcs = [f1, f2]
randFunc = random.choice(funcs)  # pick a random function from the list
randFunc.__name__

## -- End pasted text --
Out[8]: 'f1'

In [9]: randFunc(3)
Out[9]: 5
```